# How can I reproduce this top / bottom layout?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, templates, layout

[image: Document to reproduce]

Hi! I would like to make a Latex document that looks like this, with the same header on the top and the bottom. How can I replicate this ?

EDIT: I tried this :

`\fancyhead[L]{Trinity Training 2011} \fancyhead[C]{Power of a Point} \fancyhead[R]{Yufei Zhao}`

which isn't quite right with the spacing

[image: test]

Comment: Can you show what you tried, even if imperfect? If you're looking for a starting point, I'd suggest [titling](https://ctan.org/pkg/titling).

Comment: The footer is just standard stuff with fancyhdr. The top (header) is it meant to be on all pages or only on the first page?

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! The footer is only meant for the first page.

Comment: I couldn't quite start since I don't really know my way around fancyhdr... I will look at titling !

Comment: Can someone help me with the base layer of the footer ? I can't quite get it to work.

Comment: For now, I have tried this :

`\fancyhead[L]{\textbf{PCSI 3}\\ \small 2021/2022}
\fancyhead[C]{\Large \textbf{DS 1}\\ \normalsize 2 heures}
\fancyhead[R]{Lycée \textsc{Sainte-Geneviève}\\ \small Samedi 18 septembre 2021}`

which isn't quite right with the spacing...

Comment: I guess you mean the **header** is only on the first page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following I assume that the header must appear only on the first page, so I don't use `fancyhdr` for it but just place it as the first thing in the text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{array}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\fancyfoot[L]{\tiny\textsc{Devoir à la maison 5} - Inégalités et relations}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\tiny\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{-2cm}
\noindent\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lr@{}}
  PCSI 3 &  Lycée \textsc{Sainte-Geneviève}\\
  \small 2020/2021 &  15 octobre 2020 \\
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textsc{Devoir à la maison 5}} \\
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Inégalités et relations}}\\
  \hline
  & \tiny À rendre pour le lundi 9 novembre 2020
\end{tabular*}\\[1cm]
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much !

Comment: I edited a bit to make it nicer: now the whole header is in a single `tabular*`.